# Impossible to Open Android Resolver Settings

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, onesignal

I use Unity 2019.4.16f1.
I'm installing OneSignal for push notification and in the documentation, they ask to open

```
 Go to Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Settings and check the following:

    Use Jetifier
    Patch gradleTemplate.properties
    Use project settings
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/unity-sdk-setup#step-5-android-setup

When i go the the Android Resolver and click on Settings, i don't have the pop up they display in their documentation.
Please i could I do ?
What could be the cause of the issue ?

I reinstall the Android resolver without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally upgraded unity to 2020 and works fine.